# How to set the AT91 SHDN Pin in Linux/Busybox

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, embedded, shutdown, gpio

I have this AT91 SAM9G25 running a Embedded Linux with Busybox as distro. I already checked the datasheet but unfortunately I didn't get far, here's the problem:

There's a Pin SHDN for the shutdown. It is high during boot and I'd like to set it to low when hitting "poweroff" in Busybox - so the system is still powered on at this moment, it's just part of the poweroff-process.

I know I'll have to write a shutdown script in /etc/init.d/ . The problem is, I don't know which is the variable for the SHDN-Pin in Linux for the SAM9G25. Does anyone have an advise ? The only *useful* thing I got from the datasheet is, that the pin is called "SHDN" Ball=D8, but I can't work with these in Linux.

Thanks for your help

Kind Regards

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `poweroff` as there is a driver for the shutdown controller in the linux kernel. That driver is already using:

```
at91_shdwc_write(AT91_SHDW_CR, AT91_SHDW_KEY | AT91_SHDW_SHDW);
```

so the SHDN pin should be driven high.

Comment: thank you. This Pin is always high when it's on, and should be low when it's turned off, I'll be checking your command soon (not now ;). I tried the poweroff in busybox, and it didn't work, the pin value stayed the same, that's why I thought the SHDN for AT91 isn't implemented (correctly).

Answer (score 1):

You should try to check your .config file for this configurations

```
CONFIG_POWER_RESET=y
CONFIG_POWER_RESET_AT91_POWEROFF=y
CONFIG_POWER_RESET_AT91_RESET=y
```

or these:

```
CONFIG_OLD_CLK_AT91=y
CONFIG_AT91_SAM9_ALT_RESET=y
CONFIG_AT91_SAM9G45_RESET=y
CONFIG_AT91_SAM9_TIME=y
CONFIG_HAVE_AT91_SMD=y
CONFIG_SOC_AT91SAM9=y
```

depending on your kernel version